# JQuery trigger a keydown event first

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

Before asking this, I did some research on event capturing and bubbling. However, it still does not solve my problem.
I am writing an userscript for this website. Basically, I cannot change the website's code and I can only change my own userscript's code. The website has the window capture the event before my script can get it.
Here is a simplified example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  //I cannot change this code (it is part of the webpage):
  $("p")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("p");
  });
  $(window)[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("window");
  },true);

  //I can change this code (it is part of my userscript):
  $("body")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("body: I want to come first");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click Here</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit: Clarification**
for this example, I would want the "body" alert to come first, without disabling the "window" or "p" alert. So I would want the result to be either:
"body", "window", "p"
or
"body", "p", "window"

Comment: so, what is your question exactly?

Comment: didnt get it either lol. You want to prevent alerts?

Comment: the alerts are just there to demonstrate which event fires first. I want the body's click event to fire first, so basically, I want it to alert body first

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("body: I want to come first");
  });
  window.RemoveEventListener('click',alert,true);
  //I cannot change this code (it is part of the webpage):
  $("p")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("p");
  });
  $(window)[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("window");
  },true);

  //I can change this code (it is part of my userscript):

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click Here</p>

</body>
</html>
```

You can using this as i have disabled the event alert and added your script at the starting of the script tag.

Comment: This doesn't work. Using this code, nothing would happen if I clicked the body but not the p tag (since the other click events were disabled permanently).